# After submit make ajax call!

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I won't to write some values into database with ajax on submit event, after that I want to query the database (with ajax) once again to check for some response that will be written after the first ajax action. Last, if the response values are "ok" then I want to refresh the page, else I will make the query 2 secs latter till the response gets ok!

```
//Write into database form values on submit event
$('form').submit(function(){
    $.post("submitForm.php", { "array": submitedArray});

//HOW to verify if submited values where well written into databse? 
   return false;
});
```

//ONLY after submit I want to query the database and based on the response values I will refresh the page every two seconds (if response values not good) or refresh only once (if values checked are good)

```
var refresh = setInterval(function(){
      $.getJSON('someOtherScript.php', function(data){
         $.each(data, function(index, value){
           //Check values 
     });                    
      });
   }, 2000);
```

Comment: I assume you are cancelling the form submit here - otherwise the page will have gone by the time the response gets back.   If so - what is the question?  Are you saying your code doesn't work - if not what errors is occurring?

Comment: No I'm not cancelling the form I just want to get sure that the submitted form will affect database and after that query the database to check other values that depend from the submitted one's if the values that will be returned in the second ajax call are ok than I will refresh a particularly  div if not that refresh will happen every two seconds...

Comment: I am sorry, you are right I will have to cancel the form submit event with "return false;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have this correctly, you are using ajax to submit the form and want to do the check on callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml/html/script/json/jsonp',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
    // This is where you will do your get request to find the result you are looking for.
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //called when there is an error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I could not make it work properly! At the moment I'm using this: //Ajax goes here
   $.post("refreshOutputs.php", { "arrBtn": submitedRadios}, function(data){
    if(data == "1"){
     alert("Success");
     //
    }
    if(data == "0"){
     alert("Error!")
    }
   });
   return false;

Answer (score 1):

```
 onComplete: function(){
   setTimeout(function() {$("#ajaxResponse").fadeOut();}, 500);
 }
```

Write this in your ajax function and that's it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't use `setInterval`.  `setInterval` will have that code execute EVERY 2 seconds, not just after 2 seconds.  What you were looking for is `setTimeout`.  But don't use that either.

have a look at

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

post can take a `success` parameter.  This will let you run your 2nd bit of code only after the first completes.

Comment: I believe that's what I need, I mean after submit I want to query database and with the returned values do something (refresh or not the particularly div) How can I do that with the $.post ? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, $.ajax works the same as post, except its easier to get to the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the initial submit code check the database write,  if successful it returns a success code,  otherwise it returns an error code.  Either you trust ajax or you don't.

Comment: Well... what is the goal here... that the client gets confirmation the database transaction took place?  If so that doesn't need two ajax trips.  Ajax  calls can return data (or errors).  If the call returns success you know it succeeded.  If the call returns an error - or doesn't return - you can be pretty sure something went wrong.  Perhaps I misunderstand the underlying problem.  My point is if you don't trust ajax to work the first time and return a success or an appropriate error code - why do you trust it subsequent times to tell you whether it worked the first time or not.

Comment: I know I will not need two ajax trips to get confirmation from db... I will be needing two ajax trips because I will be expecting that some device will get the submited values and update the control fields... that I will have to read with the second ajax trip to update the proper div wich has information about it get it know? Thank you...

Comment: Ah ok!  So then one piece of advice.  Don't use setTimeout as you could be stacking up ajax calls.  Instead make one ajax call manually,  when that returns if it's successful stop,  otherwise at that point do a setInterval to schedule another ajax call in 2 seconds,  and repeat.

Comment: The problem is that I "can't" make the second ajax call to work... I might need some help out here :)

Comment: What about it doesn't work?  If you follow the documentation for $.ajax in the api.jquery.com docs does the call reach the server (set a breakpoint)?  If so does it return from the server? If so what happens on the client.  You pass 2 functions to $.ajax - one to call if the call succeeds and one if the call fails.  If would be very odd if one of these isn't then called on the client.  Even if you pass garbage URL for example the error function should be called on the client.